# Set cell in solver VBA by changing more than one cell?

Tags: excel, solver, vba

I am trying to use solver in Excel VBA to set a cell by changing 3 other cells. However, the three cells don't change by the values that I choose (I put a solver add in for every colomn to be bigger and lesser than specific value), it seemes like the solver can't read what I have given to it.

I need to know how to make it read the three constant and make the changes based on them.

```
Sub solver()

For i = 5 To 48
    SolverReset
    objstring = "$I$" & i

    SolverOk SetCell:=Range(objstring), MaxMinVal:=2, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:=Range("C5:E7")
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$5:$C$48", Relation:=1, FormulaText:=934000
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$5:$C$48", Relation:=3, FormulaText:=953000
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$D$" & i), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$13"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$D$" & i), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$14"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$E$" & i), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$15"
    SolverAdd CellRef:=Range("$E$" & i), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$16"

    SolverSolve userfinish:=True

Next i

End Sub
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dS7x3.jpg]

Comment: Is this a VBA problem or a solver problem? In other words, can you make the solver do what you want but can't reproduce it in VBA, or can you simply not make the solver work the way you want it to? Also -- your question talks about changing 3 cells, but your code is specifying 9 changing cells.

Answer (score 1):

I think your set up has other problems, but it's hard to tell without seeing the rows/columns in your screen cap, or knowing the formula - specifically for column I.

However, for the problem you outline:

- Although not strictly necessary ,it is simpler to not use ranges for `SetCell` and `CellRef`. Use strings.
- In the `SolverOK` statement, you should explicitly specify the `Engine`.
- In the `SolverOK` statement, `MaxMinVal:=2` is the specification to minimize. Therefore, `ValueOf` is ignored and can be omitted.
- This is a guess. You say "I am trying to ... set a cell by changing 3 other cells", but your code is changing 9 cells. In `SolverOK`, where you have `ByChange:="C5:E7"`, I suspect you want `ByChange:="C5:E5"`, and that you want the row to increment with the counter `i`.
- Another guess, you probably want to constrain `$C$5` in a similar way that you constrained `$D$5` and `$E$5`.
- Another guess - Cell `$B$13` contains the value 5000 which is your minimum value for Pi. Cell `$B$14` contains the value 8000 which is your maximum value. In `SolverAdd`, `Relation:=1` is equivalent to "less than or equal to" or "<=". `Relation:=3` is equivalent to ">=". You want to be "<=" your maximum value, and ">=" your minimum value ... you have your constraints specified backwards.

All, as illustrated below ...

```
Sub solver()

For i = 5 To 48
    SolverReset

    SolverOk SetCell:="$I$" & i, MaxMinVal:=2, ByChange:="$C$" & i & ":$E$" & i, Engine:=1
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$18"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$C$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$17"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$14"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$D$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$13"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & i, Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$B$16"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$" & i, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="$B$15"

    SolverSolve userfinish:=True

Next i

End Sub
```

Other potential problems ...

- SolverReset can leave your Excel in a Manual Calculation state, if SolverSolve is never run.
- I would guess that your error calculation is Column I, but the results you illustrate do not make any sense (e.g. qttemp - q(t)?). The value you are minimizing should be ABS(error) or error^2 - since you provided no formula, I can't tell what you have.